# Issue with curl sending on login

Tags: php, curl

I am having issue with curl sending at the time of logged into HTTPS login URL.I am trying to logged in to the site and trying to display page after logging. But Curl Giving me the HTTP 302 Error.

```
    function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}   

    function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
        $headers = array("Expect:");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($datapost);

    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($datapost);
    unset($datapost);    
}

login('https://example.com','userText=abc&passwordText=12');
$nuevo = post_data('https://example.com/Dashboard2.aspx?jhsdj=12','&nj=3');
echo $nuevo;
```

Error I am Getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Location
```

Comment: 302 is not an error. It is a redirection

Comment: yes absolutely. can you help me with that..?

Comment: You already have `curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);` in your login method, I don't know why you didn't put it in your `post_data` method.

Comment: tried it by putting into the post_data function. but it's not allow me to logged in to the system. Sending me to its login page. But i want to logged into the inner page after executing the login function.